# Writing to RandomAccessFile Asynchronously using Seek Function

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, asynchronous, upload, randomaccessfile

So, I am sending chunks of a single file asynchronously from JavaScript client. As I receive a chunk on the SpringBoot server side I want to write bytes of that chunk into a RandomAccessFile. Even though, this code works for client who sends chunks synchronously it doesn't work for asynchronous case. I am assuming the problem is caused when I call seek() in an asynchronous way. Which I believe messes the write operation. I would appreciate any help.

```
public void writeChunkRandomAccessFile(MultipartFile chunk, int chunkId, int chunkSize, String filename, int fileSize, boolean firstCall) throws IOException {

    if (chunk == null) {
        throw new StorageException("Failed to store empty file " + filename);
    }
    else if (filename.contains("..")) {
        // This is a security check
        throw new StorageException(
                "Cannot store file with relative path outside current directory "
                        + filename);
    }

    if(firstCall)
    {
        randomAccessFiletoWriteChunk = new RandomAccessFile(this.rootLocation.toString() +"/"+ filename, "rw");
        randomAccessFiletoWriteChunk.setLength(fileSize);
        System.out.println("Server created a file of size " + fileSize + " randomAccessFiletoWriteChunk has length " + randomAccessFiletoWriteChunk );
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Server wrote chunk " + chunkId + " with chunk size of " + chunk.getBytes().length + " to the index " + chunkId*chunkSize + " file size is " + randomAccessFiletoWriteChunk.length());
    randomAccessFiletoWriteChunk.seek(chunkId*chunkSize);
    System.out.println("Seek variable is changed in chunk " + chunkId);
    System.out.println("Chunk write has started for chunk " + chunkId);
    randomAccessFiletoWriteChunk.write(chunk.getBytes(),0, chunk.getBytes().length);
    System.out.println("Chunk write has completed for chunk " + chunkId);
}
```

HERE IS THE OUTPUT

Server got chunk 1

Server created a file of size 2572387

Server got chunk 0

Server got chunk 2

Server created a file of size 2572387 randomAccessFiletoWriteChunk has length java.io.RandomAccessFile@416176d3

Server called storage service to write chunk 1

Server called storage service to write chunk 0

Server called storage service to write chunk 2

Server wrote chunk 2 with chunk size of 475235 to the index 2097152 file size is 2572387

Seek variable is changed in chunk 2

Chunk write has started for chunk 2

Server wrote chunk 0 with chunk size of 1048576 to the index 0 file size is 2572387

Seek variable is changed in chunk 0

Chunk write has started for chunk 0

Server wrote chunk 1 with chunk size of 1048576 to the index 1048576 file size is 2572387

Seek variable is changed in chunk 1

Chunk write has started for chunk 1

Chunk write has completed for chunk 2

Server wrote chunk 2 to the storage

Chunk write has completed for chunk 1

Server wrote chunk 1 to the storage

Chunk write has completed for chunk 0

Server wrote chunk 0 to the storage

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do is add synchronized before the function call. Now it works perfectly fine.

```
synchronized (this){
        writeChunkRandomAccessFile(chunk,chunkkId,chunkkSize,fileName,fileeSize,false);
    }
```